# Network class freezes when form is hidden

Tags: c#

So I have a `frmMainMenu` form and a `frmMainGame` form.

I have a function that hides the main menu using delegates and shows `frmMainGame`.

In my **program.cs** I have a Network class declared
(Program.Network)

Whenever I hide `frmMainMenu` the network class basically waits for the menu to be shown again. I need the network class to run even when `frmMainMenu` is hidden.

I will send a packet to the network class trough sockets and nothing will happen until I close `frmMainGame` and show `frmMainMenu`, then the message will appear. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you call the methods of the `Network` class?
Is it threaded/timer called?

Comment: How are you displaying frmMainGame?...how do you know when something has arrived in the network?  It could be as simple as you have the wrong form references...we have no idea.

Comment: there's a Socket receive handler that handles data.

I call it through Program.cs 

network Network = new network(new socket(SocketInformation));

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the main thread for networking, and while no ui, the message queue wait till there is something to show.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a sample of using the default thread pool to do stuff in background threads.

the is also a nice class called BackgroundWorker you can use to report progress to ui.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense, but I don't have knowledge on how to create a new thread for the network class that can be used throughout everyclass on the program.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to create a new thread:

```
public static System.Threading.Thread Network;

static void Main()
{
    Network = new System.Threading.Thread(NetworkMethod);  // Insert Name of your method here
    Network.Start();

    // Run your normal application
}
static void NetworkMethod()
{
    // Do stuff that would block the UI
}
```

Comment: But I have a whole class of methods to run. how would I run the whole class as a thread instead of one void?

Comment: You probably have one method calling these other methods in a certain order. Just extract the initialization logic and this call method into the single method and call that one in a new thread. If you need more help, you will have to show us an outline of your code.